# Objeto como parametro de entrada en un metodo de clase java para Webservice Rest swagger

Tags: java, swagger

Tengo el siguiente método el cual es llamado desde swagger:

```
@POST
    @Path("v1/getDatosGestionCliente.json/{idCess}")
    @ApiOperation(value= "Recupera las gestiones abiertas de un cliente", response = SDatosGestionClienteDG.class)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getDatosGestionCliente(@ApiParam(value = "ID CESS", required=true) @PathParam("idCess") String idCess) throws ECIExceptionGeneral{
...
}
```

En un principio tengo como parámetro de entrada idCess pero tengo que modificarlo teniendo que añadir seis parámetros mas de entrada. Mi pregunta es si puedo crear una clase con todos estos parámetros y ponerlo en el método como parametro de entrada. En caso afirmativo, me gustaría saber como declararlo.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0):

Sí se puede, usando las anotaciones `@ApiModel` y `@ApiModelProperty`.

```
@ApiModel
public class MiClase{
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "ID CESS", required=true) 
    private String idCess;
    ...
}
```

Y el método original:

```
@POST
@Path("v1/getDatosGestionCliente.json/{idCess}")
@ApiOperation(value= "Recupera las gestiones abiertas de un cliente", response = SDatosGestionClienteDG.class)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getDatosGestionCliente(MiClase datosEntrada) throws ECIExceptionGeneral{
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Entiendo que en Swagger podre controlar los parametros de entrada cuando escriba sobre ellos